# Batch file called from Javascript/XPCOM doesn't show command prompt window

Tags: javascript, batch-file, xpcom

I am calling a batch file from Javascript in this fashion:

```
function runBatch(){
    var exe = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/file/local;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    exe.initWithPath("C:\\test.bat");
    var run = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/process/util;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
    run.init(exe);
    var parameters = ["hi"];
    run.run(false, parameters,parameters.length);
}
```

my test batch file is:

```
echo on
echo %1 
pause
exit
```

Each time I call a batch file, however, the command prompt is not displayed, as it would be if I simply ran the batch file from the desktop.  How can I remedy this and display a command prompt for the batch file?

**Edit**
To be clear, the cmd.exe process is launched - I can see it in the task bar.  But no window gets displayed.  This snippet behaves similarly:

```
function runCmd(){  
var exe = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/file/local;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
exe.initWithPath("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe");
var run = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/process/util;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
run.init(exe);
run.run(false, null,0);
}
```

Comment: FWIW, your first snippet works fine for me on Vista and Firefox 3.6.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I've heard so far (that should work, although I haven't done it yet, comes from Mook in the Mozilla xulrunner IRC channel:

*create* a temporary batch file, writing in the batch file to call and arguments to pass it.  then execute the temporary batch file.

e.g psuedocode:

```
f = fopen("temp.bat"); 
fprintf(f, "other.bat 1 2 3 4 5"); 
fclose(f); 
exec("temp.bat");
```

not very elegant but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using the launch method of nsiLocalFile?

```
function runBatch(){
    var exe = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/file/local;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    exe.initWithPath("C:\\test.bat");
    exe.launch();
}
```

This should have "[the same effect as if you double-clicked the file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Running_applications#Using_nsILocalFile.launch())."

Comment: Yes. - this will open and show the window but will not let me pass parameters/arguments (which I failed to mention in my question)

Comment: Which led me to ... create a shortcut that has the parameters defined, and I can call the shortcut using nsiLocalFile... and the batch files gets run.  But I want to have the parameters be dynamic.

Comment: Is there a way to create a shortcut on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet seems to work fine. Of course, you have to change D:\Windows\system32\ to path to cmd.exe in your operation system.

```
const FileFactory = new Components.Constructor("@mozilla.org/file/local;1","nsILocalFile","initWithPath");
var str_LocalProgram = "D:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";
var obj_Program = new FileFactory(str_LocalProgram); 
var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
process.init(obj_Program);
var args = ["/C", "regedit.exe"];
process.run(true, args, args.length);
```

Comment: @0A0D to make sure that code past `process.run` will be executed *after* changes have been made.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing right but repair this:

```
function runBatch(){
    var exe = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/file/local;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    exe.initWithPath("***C:\&nbsp;\test.bat***");
    var run = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/process/util;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
    run.init(exe);
    var parameters = ["hi"];
    run.run(false, parameters,parameters.length);
}
```

If you do this???

```
function runBatch(){
    var exe = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/file/local;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    exe.initWithPath("***C:\test.bat***");
    var run = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/process/util;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
    run.init(exe);
    var parameters = ["hi"];
    run.run(false, parameters,parameters.length);
}
```

An put @echo off at init???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to launch a batch file and pass in an argument. This is how I did it:

```
    let file = uri.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIFileURL).file;

    let run = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/process/util;1']
                        .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);

    let path = file.path;

    if(file.exists())
    {
        // quick security check
        if(file.isExecutable())
        {
            // show error message
            return;
        }

        let localfile = file.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);

        if(localfile != null)
        {
            if (app == "app1")
            {
               localfile.initWithPath("C:\\app1.bat");            
            }
            else
            {
               localfile.initWithPath("C:\\app2.bat");
            }
            run.init(localfile);
            var parameters = [path];
            run.run(false, parameters, parameters.length);
        }
        else
        {
           // show error message
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // show error message
    }
```

and in my Window batch file I did:

```
@ECHO OFF
START "application.exe" %1
```

using START, allowed me to launch the application and close the command line window

Answer (score -1):

Pfft, very ugly code..
A much nicer trick is to use Win.com to spawn a 16bit subsystem of the command prompt.
Win.com will send the console to the right virtual terminal, showing you the output.

```
var lPath = getWorkingDir.path + "\\..\\..\\WINDOWS\\system32\\win.com";
lFile.initWithPath(lPath);
var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
process.init(lFile);
 var args = ["cmd.exe"];
process.run(false, args, args.length);
```

Nicer, and works :)

Answer (score -1):

For Linux:

```
<script>

    function callLight2()
    {

        netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege(
        'UniversalXPConnect'
    );
        var exe = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/file/local;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    // exe.initWithPath(C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"");
        exe.initWithPath("/usr/bin/gnome-terminal");

        var run = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/process/util;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
        run.init(exe);        

        var parameters = ["-e", "/usr/bin/ip_connect_up.sh 2 2 3 4 5 6"];
    // var parameters = ["/C", "regedit.exe"];
    // var parameters = ["hi"];
        run.run(true, parameters,parameters.length);

    }


</script>


<a href="#" onClick ="callLight2()">start</a>
```

Comment: This is a Windows question